# type class and binding reuse inside expressions in haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am not really sure why the two intermediate expressions do not type check. The type checker seems to freshen new type bindings for each occurence of `m`. is there an extension to allow reusing the name `m` in all those locations?

```
test ::  MonadPlus m => m a
test =
    let r = mzero :: m a  -- fails 
    in let r' :: m a = mzero  -- fails
       in  mzero
```

Comment: [ScopedTypeVariables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables) but in this case here you don't use `r` nor `r'` so I fail to see your point - maybe you can find an better example?

Comment: I want to write expressions incrementally, using undefined first in various places. thats why I would wish to constraint the types that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax       #-}

test :: ∀ m a . MonadPlus m => m a
test =
    let r = mzero :: m a
    in let r' :: m a = mzero
       in  mzero
```

If you don't like non-ASCII characters in your code, you can also omit the `-XUnicodeSyntax` and use the `forall` keyword in place of ∀.

What this keyword does is,

1. it introduces the new type variables `m` and `a`, as *universally quantified*. Now, usually Haskell just assumes that *any* type variable which hasn't yet been mentioned in the same(!) signature is universal. But
2. it disables automatic introduction of type variables, within the whole context scope. This includes also `r = mzero :: m a`, so at that point GHC knows it's *not* supposed to introduce `m` and `a` as new variables, but re-use the same `m` and `a` as in the signature of `test`.

Comment: Will upvote if you explain what the forall keyword/symbol does here.

Comment: `forall a .` is like a `\a ->` for types. Normally when you write a signature like `f :: a -> [a]` where does the `a` come from? We recognize that its meaning is "some unknown type variable", but this is formalized by writing `f :: forall a . a -> [a]`. In fact, Haskell automatically desugars things to that.